# Pass data between Tabbar with protocol and delegate

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

Is it possible to pass data between my tabs (View controllers) using protocol and delegate? (I know how to pass data easily with notification center between tab bars and I know how to pass data "back" to other VC using protocol and delegates)

I am trying to minimise the use of NSNotification center as they are abit messy. That is why I think protocol would be better

For example,

I have a tab (PostTab) that makes a post and a tab (DisplayTab) that displays a post. When the postTab makes a post, allow the DisplayTab to have a delegate function called

```
func postAdded(post: Post) { //Display post }
```

where post is the passed from the PostTab.

Answer (score 1):

If I can suggest:

**1. option:**

I typed it very simplified - it is possible more simple way, so:

Into your PostTab controller, to the line, where you are ready with data from user:

```
let index = 1 //you know a real index of our displayTab controller
let displayTabViewController = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?[index] as! DisplayTabViewController        
displayTabViewController.postAdded(post: POST)
```

And this to be placed into your DisplayTab controller:

```
func postAdded(post: Post)
{
    print("This is the: \(post)")
}
```

**2. option:**

Use AppDelegate as a delegate or make your own delegate.

Answer (score 0):

Not out of the box since there is not protocol which supports sharing arbitrary data. You have to implement you own protocol.